# Custom compilation command fails on Windows due to slashes in paths

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, filenames

when i type on "shell":

> c:\Users\TR\Desktop\emacs-27.2-x86_64\bin\GAMES\game3>love .

works fine but when i put

```
(defun insert-file-name ()
 (interactive)
 (let ((compilation-ask-about-save  nil))
 (compile (concat (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)) "love ."))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-v") #'insert-file-name)
```

in my initialization file using "C-c C-v" gives me the error message:

> -*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "c:/Users/TR/Desktop/emacs-27.2-x86_64/bin/GAMES/game3/"
> -*-
> Compilation started at Sun Apr 18 23:30:16
> c:/Users/TR/Desktop/emacs-27.2-x86_64/bin/GAMES/game3/love .
> 'c:/Users/TR/Desktop/emacs-27.2-x86_64/bin/GAMES/game3/love' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Apr 18 23:30:16

a similar code worked on Ubuntu emacs, but on Windows 7 it does not work!

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I do not know, if that is an issue, but have you noticed the use of `/` vs `\ `?

Comment: I'm guessing this question is a duplicate...

Comment: Start [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html).

Comment: And [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [backslashes in strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).
And learn about [manipulating file names](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html).

The result of evaluating this is presumably the absolute file name that you want for your program:

```lisp
(expand-file-name "love" "c:\\Users\\TR\\Desktop\\emacs-27.2-x86_64\\bin\\GAMES\\game3")
```

That is:

```lisp
(expand-file-name "love" (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer,

pass the relative file path to the cli. See documentation of `file-relative-name`.

Long answer,

As I can see in first paragraph. The shell is *DOS* shell. When current work directory is "c:\Users\TR\Desktop\emacs-27.2-x86_64\bin\GAMES\game3", you can run "love" (note it's relative path) without any problem.

But when you run `M-x compile`, you pass the whole path "c:/Users/TR/Desktop/emacs-27.2-x86_64/bin/GAMES/game3/love" to the *DOS* shell.

The *DOS* shell can't recognise the path.

You can convert the path by replacing the "/" with "" by `(replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\\\\" "c:/hello/world.txt")`.

But it's better to use relative path which is portable on all environments (WSL, Cygwin, macOS, Linux ...)

In your code, instead of using full path `(concat (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)) "love .")`, you should use `(concat (file-name-relative (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))) "love .")`.

Here is the documentation of `file-relative-name`,

```
file-relative-name is a compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.

(file-relative-name FILENAME &optional DIRECTORY)

Convert FILENAME to be relative to DIRECTORY (default: ‘default-directory’).
This function returns a relative file name that is equivalent to FILENAME
when used with that default directory as the default.
If FILENAME is a relative file name, it will be interpreted as existing in
‘default-directory’.
```

You might need set `default-directory` to the right working directory inside your function `insert-file-name` before calling `compile`. But looks it's correct according to the error message.

Comment: Please consider elaborating, perhaps summarizing a relevant portion of that doc or providing an example.